# Ubuntu-Server bash colors not appearing on login

Tags: ssh, bash, shell, color

I am running Ubuntu Server 8.04 (hardy), and when I login remotely i can't see the colors when using ls, however after I type "bash" into the shell I see colors, I've already checked my .bashrc and all the colors are enabled by default (colors=auto), and I've checked "echo $SHELL" and "which bash", and they both report /bin/bash however as I already mentioned I don't see colors until I enter "bash" into shell
Why might this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either

- Input your commands directly into ~/.bash_profile
- Source your .bashrc from your ~/.bash_profile

e.g.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

.bashrc is used for interactive shells, .bash_profile is used for login shells.

Comment: By default Ubuntu provides a ~/.profile instead of a ~/.bash_profile. You might want to check for the existences of a .profile before you create a .bash_profile.

Comment: Andol, your answer was the solution, I had manually created a ~/.bash_profile file instead of editing ~/.profile, and that's what was causing the issue.  How can I accept your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this command 

echo exec bash -login > .login

Then the next time you log in the colors should work

Comment: Nope, I wouldn't recommend it.